# There will be errors in table by using IET communications template document

Tags: tables, errors, templates

I'm trying to use IET communications template but have difficult in table design. The template can be found at

***http://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_ResearchJournals_latex.zip***

What I want is like[image]
The code is

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table*}[!t]
\centering
\scriptsize
\caption{A Comparative Description of Different Algorithms}
\label{table3}

\begin{tabular}{|m{1.5cm}<{\centering}|m{4.5cm}<{\centering}|m{3.5cm}
<{\centering}|m{2cm}<{\centering}|m{3cm}<{\centering}|m{1cm}<{\centering}|} 
    \hline
    \textbf{1}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{6} \\ 
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{1.5cm}{\textbf{A}} & B & C  & D& E  & \cite{1-17} \\ 
    \cline{2-6} 
    & B& C  & D  & E  & \cite{1-18}  \\ 
    \cline{2-6} 
    & B  &C & D & E & \cite{1-18} \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

But if I use the template document style/class, it will be like this:
[image]
The code is

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}{}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table*}[!t]
\centering
\scriptsize
\caption{A Comparative Description of Different Algorithms}
\label{table3}

\begin{tabular}{|m{1.5cm}<{\centering}|m{4.5cm}<{\centering}|m{3.5cm}
<{\centering}|m{2cm}<{\centering}|m{3cm}<{\centering}|m{1cm}<{\centering}|} 
    \hline
    \textbf{1}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{6} \\ 
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{1.5cm}{\textbf{A}} & B & C  & D& E  & \cite{1-17} \\ 
    \cline{2-6} 
    & B& C  & D  & E  & \cite{1-18}  \\ 
    \cline{2-6} 
    & B  &C & D & E & \cite{1-18} \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

And errors is *Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. ... {\cite{1-21}} \ \cline{2-6}*

It puzzles me for a long time. Appreciate your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). We kindly suggest you to show a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `cta-author` class does not allow to use `\cline` (nor `\cmidrule`).

I'd suggest to you to load `booktabs` and use `\cmidrule`.

The class documentation says:

> To get the table caption use the command \processtable{....}, ensure
>   to insert a brace { before \begin{tabular} and closing brace } after
>   \end{tabular}

hence I have modified your code accordingly.

Moreover, I think that the definition of the cell with `\multirow{2}{1.5cm}{\textbf{A}}` should be refined according to the actual text in it.

Finally, since your MWE is not complete, the citation are shown as `?`.

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!t]
        \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
        \processtable{A Comparative Description of Different Algorithms\label{table3}}
        {\begin{tabular}{m{1.5cm}<{\centering}m{4.5cm}<{\centering}m{3.5cm}
                    <{\centering}m{2cm}<{\centering}m{3cm}<{\centering}m{1cm}<{\centering}}
                \toprule 
                \textbf{1}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{6} \\
                \midrule
                \multirow{2}{1.5cm}{\textbf{A}} & B & C  & D& E  & \cite{1-17} \\
                \cmidrule{2-6}
                & B& C  & D  & E  & \cite{1-18} \\
                \cmidrule{2-6} 
                & B  &C & D & E & \cite{1-18} \\
                \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}{}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]